# Django DRF Serializer StringRelatedField not returning null

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need a StringRelatedField to return null when there is a null value.

These are the models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 )

class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categories', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

This is the serializer

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='category.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
        'task_name',
        'category',  
        'category_name',
          ]
```

**Current Results**

When 'category' id not null, the correct data is returned

```
{
    "task_name": "123",
    "category": 1,
    "category_name": django,
}
```

With 'category' id null the 'category_name' is not returned.

```
{
    "task_name": "123",
    "category": null,
}
```

**Required Results**

When 'category' id null still return "category_name" as null.

```
{
    "task_name": "123",
    "category": null,
    "category_name": null,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all serializers can have parameter **allow_null** so in your case it will look like:

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='category.name', allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
        'task_name',
        'category',  
        'category_name',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `allow_null=True` options to the `StringRelatedField` field. So, try this;

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source="category.name", allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
            "task_name",
            "category",  
            "category_name",
        ]
```